# How is the source term chosen when using path integrals?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

Suppose I would like to compute (time ordered) vacuum expectation values for a quantum field theory by using the path integral approach. Using the Lagrangian for the theory, we define a generating functional $Z[f]$ where $f$ is the source term. The vacuum expectation values are obtained by taking functional derivatives of $Z[f]$.

I have read that $f$ can be interpreted as either a purely mathematical tool or as a physical field with sources/sinks that creates/annihilate particles. In either case, the functional derivatives will depend on our choice of $f$, so how do we choose it so that it is "physically relevant"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the sources $f$ are only used as a generating device and put to zero at the end of the calculation.