# How to understand the source term $J$ in the path integral formulation of QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, correlation-functions

I am learning QFT using the path integral approach, and I am confused about the role of the source term $J$ in the Lagrangian. I know that it is a mathematical trick that allows us to calculate $n$-point functions, which are the coefficients of the Taylor expansion of the generating functional $Z[J]$ with respect to $J$. But I don’t understand what $J$ physically represents, and how it relates to the propagation of particles. Can someone explain this to me in both words and mathematical form?
I appreciate any help and or insight.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: @JohnA. I started QFT with Tom Lancaster book “QFT for the gifted amateur”.

Comment: Damn I wish it were Srednicki so I could point you to the right chapters. Have you gotten to Feynman diagrams? (Ch 9 in Srednicki)

Comment: No problem I can check it could you please reference it?

Comment: There is a freely available preprint on srednicki’s website (just look up his name and his college UCSB) and you will get to the pdf. check out chapter 9

Comment: I will check it, thank you.

Comment: If you still have questions after reading that (it does a much better job than a single post can probably do), feel free to edit your question.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/755176/2451

Answer (score 1):

Physically, $J$ represents an external force (or "source") that is put in by hand to excite the field.

It's perhaps easier to understand what it represents in a simpler model. Consider a $0+1$ dimensional field theory (also known as a classical particle!). The action with a source is
$$
S = \int dt \left(\frac{1}{2} m \dot{q}^2 - V(q) + qJ(t) \right)
$$
Then the Euler-Lagrange equations are
$$
m \ddot{q} + V'(q) = J(t)
$$
Here you can see $J$ is appearing in the same role as an external, in general time-dependent force acting on $q$.

Comment: but how can I see annihilation/creation process in it.

Comment: @Roden At a heuristic / intuitive level, if you put in a source (or sink) at some location in spacetime, you will create (or absorb) some excitations in the field. You can think of these excitations as being collections of particles. At a rigorous level, the [LSZ formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_reduction_formula) relates correlation functions (which is what you directly get by differentiating the partition function with respect to the source) to scattering amplitudes.